# Android Content Resolver delete - update status

Tags: java, android, database, android-contentprovider

Is it possible to get notified when I delete an element using `ContentResolver`?

For example, if I execute this:

```
context.getContentResolver().delete(SMS_URI, null, null);
```

it returns the number of rows deleted. But if I delete 10k element it might take some time. I want to update `progressbar` during deleting and I think that deleting it one by one might be not optimal solution.

Answer (score 2):

As you can look at the documentation all one has to do is to add:

```
 context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(SMS_URI, null);
```

Some example for a better understanding:

[Android Tutorial: Writing your own Content Provider](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-writing-your-own-content-provider/)